# Rails 3 Models containing Themselves?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm currently working towards making a nested type object model and I was curious how I would handle this with Rails 3.

Basically I have the following:

- Assertion
- Expression_Group
- Expression

The Assertion is made up of 1-N Expression_Groups.  The Expression_Groups are made up of 1-N Expressions.  The tricky part for me with ORM and this is, the Expression_Groups may also be made up of other Expression_Groups.

Think of a SQL SELECT and say we're building the WHERE clause.

```
((V > 2 AND X = 0) OR (Y > 2 OR (Z = 4 OR S <> 2)))
```

When looking at something like that, we can break it down and say:

```
 Z = 4 - Expression
(Z = 4 OR S <> 2) - Expression Group
(Y > 2 OR (Z = 4 OR S <> 2)) - Expression Group CONTAINING Expression AND Expression_Group
```

And so on.  What I would like to do, is give the user the ability to build that structure.  I would like to use Rails 3 and build my Models in such a way that I don't have to roll-your-own processor and can simply use the forms as they are.

I know how to set up every relationship EXCEPT for the Expression_Groups containing Expression_Groups.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a potential *one to many* relationship between `ExpressionGroup` objects, an association like this may work:

```
has_many :child_expression_groups,
         :class_name => "ExpressionGroup",
         :foreign_key => "parent_id",
         :dependent => :destroy
```

Note, this will require a new field - `parent_id` in your `expression_groups` table that is allowed to be null and contains the ID of the parent `ExpressionGroup` (if there is a parent).

Then, you can get all the *top level* expression groups by retrieving only those in your system that have `parent_id` set to `nil` (or defining a scope for this in the `ExpressionGroup` model).

If you need more advanced handling (like making it a *many to many*, and so on), look into using something like [Ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry).

Comment: I did have a parent_id in my expression_groups table, but I did not have the relationship like you have. I'll give that a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Great, good luck! Like I said, if you want to go a bit deeper I would highly recommend using something that provides a higher level of abstraction (like Ancestry). But if your needs are simple then something like this should suffice :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered `has_and_belongs_to_many` ? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: no, I haven't.  I see the example they have, which would lead me to believe that I would put that in my Assertion class pointing to :ExpressionGroup.  Is that correct?  Their example makes sense, but when I put it against the verbage of has_and_belongs_to_many, I can't string it together.  So an Assertion has ExpressionGroup and belongs to many ExpressionGroups?  Or does that infer that ExpressionGroups belongs to many other ExpressionGroups?

Comment: IF I understand your problem correctly, ExpressionGroup `has_and_belongs_to_many :expression_groups` and `belongs_to :assertion` and `has_many :expressions`, Assertion `has_many :expression_groups`, and Expression `belongs_to :expression_group`

Comment: I believe you've summed it up well - and now I see, from your description, that you meant has_and_belongs_to_many for ExpressionGroup.  I'll try that too! Thanks!